# Insert from python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

How to insert data from code below?
I have a code below

```
latitude1 = -6.208470935786019
longitude1 = 106.81796891087399
new_data = [[latitude1, longitude1]]
preds = model.predict(new_data)
preds

arr = [latitude1,longitude1]
arrcon = np.concatenate((arr,preds))
print(arrcon) #[-6.208470935786019 106.81796891087399 'Not Categorized']

listarcon= arrcon.tolist()
print(listarcon) #[-6.208470935786019, 106.81796891087399, 'Not Categorized']

#make the list into multi list
singlearcon = np.array(listarcon).reshape(1,3)
print(singlearcon) #[['-6.208470935786019' '106.81796891087399' 'Not Categorized']]
```

This is insert into database code

```
mycursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO traveldata (Latitude,Longitude,Wisata) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = (listarcon[0],listarcon[1],listarcon[2])
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

[image: example]

How to insert it to database? the data didn't seem to get to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing a transaction `mycursor.execute(sql, val)`, we should **commit** the change `mycursor.commit()`

Reference for the **commit method** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html

An example of insert code https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Comment: Yess thankyouu, i get this AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit' but when i search another alternative conn.commit() works for me instead :)